# tiff2ps and ps2pdf not scaling to A4 paper size

Tags: linux, pdf, tiff, postscript

I'm trying to convert a sequence of TIFF files to one PDF file, using `tiff2ps` and `ps2pdf` superposition:

```
tiff2ps *.tif > d1p.ps && \
ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dOptimize=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true d1p.ps
```

But instead of scaling images to A4 format it cats them in the bottom left corner. I've uploaded the samples to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sn67d5tim43rzm9/AACuCkkjNKPGzJMhtgppzvmLa?dl=0). As you can see, `-sPAPERSIZE=a4` doesn't help me.

Does someone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-dPDFFitPage` to your `ps2pdf` command line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that besides `tiff2ps` there is also a `tiff2pdf` command?

It would spare you from running 2 different utilities.

```
$ tiff2pdf -h

 LIBTIFF, Version 4.0.3
 Copyright (c) 1988-1996 Sam Leffler
 Copyright (c) 1991-1996 Silicon Graphics, Inc.

 usage:  tiff2pdf [options] input.tiff
 options:
  -o: output to file name
  -j: compress with JPEG
  -z: compress with Zip/Deflate
  -q: compression quality
  -n: no compressed data passthrough
  -d: do not compress (decompress)
  -i: invert colors
  -u: set distance unit, 'i' for inch, 'm' for centimeter
  -x: set x resolution default in dots per unit
  -y: set y resolution default in dots per unit
  -w: width in units
  -l: length in units
  -r: 'd' for resolution default, 'o' for resolution override
  -p: paper size, eg "letter", "legal", "A4"
  -F: make the tiff fill the PDF page
  -f: set PDF "Fit Window" user preference
  -e: date, overrides image or current date/time default, YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
  -c: sets document creator, overrides image software default
  -a: sets document author, overrides image artist default
  -t: sets document title, overrides image document name default
  -s: sets document subject, overrides image image description default
  -k: sets document keywords
  -b: set PDF "Interpolate" user preference
  -h: usage
```

`tiff2pdf` has no support for multiple TIFF input files, though. But OTOH it supports multipage TIFFs...